# DefaultContractResolver: CreateContract vs ResolveContract

Tags: serialization, json.net, deserialization

What is difference between `CreateContract` and `ResolveContract` methods of an [DefaultContractResolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver.htm) instance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at [the code](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/10.0.3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs), you will notice that [`ResolveContract`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/10.0.3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L171) is the only public method of `DefaultContractResolver` (not counting the constructor).  This method  is defined by the [`IContractResolver`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/10.0.3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/IContractResolver.cs) interface, which `DefautContractResolver` implements.  It is used to *resolve* (that is, get or create) the [`JsonContract`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/10.0.3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonContract.cs) for a particular object type.

The `DefaultContractResolver` uses caching internally.  When `ResolveContract` is called, it first looks in its cache to see if there is already an existing contract for the given type.  If so, it returns it; otherwise, it calls the protected [`CreateContract`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/10.0.3/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/DefaultContractResolver.cs#L1136) method to create the contract and add it to the cache.

So, in short, `CreateContract` is just an implementation detail of `DefaultContractResolver`, while `ResolveContract` is the public interface.

Comment: Ah, yes! Why didn't I look at the source code before? Thanks!